# Discord.py Purge command not purging

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I can't figure out why its not purging it's probably me just being stupid but if someone could point it out that would be great thanks

```
@client.command(aliases=["clean"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
    authors = {}
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=amount + 1):
        if message.author not in authors:
            authors[message.author] = 1
        else:
            authors[message.author] += 1
        message.delete()

    msg = "\n".join([f"{author}:{amount}" for author, amount in authors.items()])
    await ctx.channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: Maybe try `await message.delete()`

Comment: `message.delete()` is a courotine, so you have to await it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Benjin and PaxxPatriot its working now its a little bit slow for a purge command but dose what it needs to do

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
    authors = {}
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=amount + 1):
        if message.author not in authors:
            authors[message.author] = 1
        else:
            authors[message.author] += 1
        await message.delete()

    msg = "\n".join([f"{author}:{amount}" for author,
                     amount in authors.items()])
    await ctx.channel.send(msg)```
````